# Can I gift Final Fantasy XIV to a friend?

Tags: final-fantasy-14

Final Fantasy XIV is sold out in every retail store it seems. I can purchase it online, but I want to gift it to a friend and not create an account for myself. Can I purchase a digital copy of FFXIV as a gift and give the account to someone else?

Comment: Purchase it on Steam as a gift.

Comment: @Ramhound It's not available on Steam.

Comment: @cloudymusic It is now.

Answer (score 5):

The "digital download" version of FFXIV:ARR simply e-mails the purchaser a product registration key, which you (or another person) can then register to your Square-Enix account. Therefore, you should be able to purchase a key and then give that key to someone else so they can register it on their own account.

Disclaimer: I only have first-hand experience with this on the North American Square-Enix online store, so I cannot completely guarantee that this is true for other regions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you go to [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002BRZ79E) to purchase it, you can easily gift it for someone else. You can choose what system (console, PC, PC download, etc.) on there.

Answer (score 1):

I just bought the game for my boyfriend!

- **Go to the Square Enix store**
- **Purchase the Digital Download for PC FFXIV:ARR**

  - MAKE SURE IT'S **[PC DOWNLOAD]**, NOT JUST [PC]
- **Verified my purchase via SMS/Text**
- **Once Verified, Go to your email and retrieve the Activation code which is used as the registration**
- **Give that code to your friend/recruit/loved one.**

*The process worked, and he then registered as my Recruit. If you didnt download the game already, it will prompt you to start the download for the full game.*

I hope that clarifies the process for you!